# error An unexpected error occurred: "EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink when trying to install decorators

Tags: reactjs, decorator, mobx-react

I am getting this error when I run `yarn add babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy --dev`  So it wont install the plugin into the dependancies. The error is the following.

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink  '/Volumes/server2/Desktop/JavaScript/bird-cage/node_modules/neo- async/mapLimit.js'".
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using Windows? [This might give some clues](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/119#issuecomment-398590946).

Comment: No I am not using Windows. I am on a Mac.